# Analysing CPU/Memory usage while UI Automation

Tags: ios, terminal, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am automating my iOS app using UIAutomation framework from terminal. Now i want to analyse CPU and Memory usage of application while automation, again using terminal. Does instruments allow using 2 trace templates at a time (Automation and Activity Monitor in my case)?